# Node.js (with Express.js) not working with Share.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sharejs

I'm following the docs on the github of Share.js but can't seem to get it to work

https://github.com/share/ShareJS/wiki/Getting-started-%280.6.x%29

I built a base app with the Express generator. It put the main server file inside /bin/www which is not supposed to be modified (I tried it).

The problem is with the code below.

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    sharejs = require('share').server;

var server = connect(
      connect.logger(),
      connect.static(__dirname + '/public')
    );
var options = {db: {type: 'none'}}; // See docs for options. {type: 'redis'} to enable persistance.

// Attach the sharejs REST and Socket.io interfaces to the server
sharejs.attach(server, options);

server.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
});
```

It requires me to set up server.listen(...) in the app.js but it's already been done in the /bin/www file.

My app.js looks like the code below.

```
var express = require('express');
var engine = require('ejs-locals');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');



var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// database setup
var dbConfig = require('./db.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// connect to DB
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Configuring Passport
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: 'mySecretKey',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

 // Using the flash middleware provided by connect-flash to store messages in session
 // and displaying in templates
var flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash());

// Initialize passport
var initPassport = require('./passport/init');
initPassport(passport);

// Configuring Routes
var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
var users = require('./routes/users');
var editor = require('./routes/editor')(passport);
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/editor', editor);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  if (req.session.user) {
    app.locals.user = req.session.user
  }
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});



module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Try this in your `app.js` (right before the `module.exports` line): `sharejs.attach(app, options)` (+ move the relevant require and options there as well).